# I have different values between 0 & 1 and cutoffs (H,M, L) for all 3 models. So how to combine them all such that I get scaled values & cutoffs?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, optimization, normal-distribution

```
model_A output    model_B output      model_c output
0.3                  0.7                 0.8
0.5                  0.2                 0.1
0.4                  0.8                 0.5
0.9                  0.9                 0.6
0.1                  0.3
0.2
Model_A : High_cutoff > 0.5
          Medium_cutoff between 0.3 & 0.5
          Low_cutoff < 0.3
Model_B : High_cutoff > 0.8
          Medium_cutoff between 0.7 & 0.8
          Low_cutoff < 0.7
Model_C : High_cutoff > 0.7
          Medium_cutoff between 0.4 & 0.7
          Low_cutoff < 0.4
```

I want scale and standardize my cutoffs. But, after z-transform my cutoffs gets messed up at last. Please help me to get a single cutoff at last. Please look at the below code.

```
# Data set.
modelA.output <- c(0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2)
modelB.output <- c(0.7, 0.2, 0.8, 0.9, 0.3)
modelC.output <- c(0.8, 0.1, 0.5, 0.6)

# Create a list that contains all data
output <- list(A=modelA.output, B=modelB.output, C=modelC.output)


# Create the data set and use the list to extract data and model names.
data <- data.frame(output=unlist(output),model=rep(names(output), sapply(output, length)))

# Prepare a named vector of cut-offs and use the label

# to insert them into the data frame in the appropriate places

# (names of cutoff.high must correspond to values in data$model).

# Note: cutoffs for medium are not needed, they flow from high and low.

cutoff.high <- c(A=0.5, B=0.8, C=0.7)
data$cutoff.high <- cutoff.high[data$model]
cutoff.low <- c(A=0.3, B=0.7, C=0.4)
data$cutoff.low <- cutoff.low[data$model]

# Group the data according to limits

data$grouped <- with(data,ifelse(output > cutoff.high, "high",
                          ifelse(output < cutoff.low, "low", "medium") ))

print(data) 

#SCALING to get combined cutoffs
data_low <- data[data$grouped=="low",]
data_medium <- data[data$grouped=="medium",]
data_high <- data[data$grouped=="high",]


low_mean <- mean(log(data_low$output))
low_sd <- sd(log(data_low$output))
scaled_low <- log(data_low$output)-low_mean/low_sd

> scaled_low
[1] 1.436232 2.129379 2.129379 2.534845 1.436232

medium_mean <- mean(log(data_medium$output))
medium_sd <- sd(log(data_medium$output))
scaled_medium <- log(data_medium$output)-medium_mean/medium_sd

> scaled_medium
[1] 0.7630865 1.2739121 1.0507686 1.6103844 1.7439157 1.2739121 1.4562337


high_mean <- mean(log(data_high$output))
high_sd <- sd(log(data_high$output))
scaled_high <- log(data_high$output)-high_mean/high_sd

> scaled_high
[1] 2.021362 2.021362 1.903579
```

I want to get scaled values instead of original values and also single scaled cutoff for High, Medium and Low.

Basically I want to generalize values and cutoff from all three cases.

I have different values between 0 & 1 and cutoffs (H,M, L) for all 3 models. So how to combine them all such that I get scaled values & cutoffs. [Check for Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdvB7.png)

In above image i have attached a example where I got 0.3 for model A in medium category while 0.3 from model B in low category. But, I want to generalize and get one cutoff across all values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your desired lower cut off point be $L^*$ and high cut-off be $H^*$.

Let $x_{ij}$ be the $j$-th input from model $i$ with corresponding cut off $L_i$ and $H_i$ respectively, assuming that $H_i > L_i$.

To map $(H_i, L_i)$ to $(H^*, L^*)$,

$$y_i=\frac{H^*-L^*}{H_i-L_i}(x_i-L_i)+L^*$$

Edit:

With new restriction of the new value must be between $0$ and $1$.

Suppose the cut off value are determined by quantile $q_L$ and $q_H$ where $0< q_L < q_H < 1$.

$$y_i = \begin{cases}\frac{q_L}{L_i}x_i, & x_i \leq L_i\\ \frac{q_H-q_L}{H_i-L_i}(x_i-L_i)+q_L,& L_i < x_i < H_i\\ \frac{1-q_H}{1-H_i}(x_i-H_i)+q_H,& x_i \geq H_i \end{cases}$$

Comment: But, what if I don't know desired cutoff prior. I need to calculate cutoffs based on values.

Comment: what is the physical meaning of your cutoff points?

Comment: Each data point is a probablility of getting a disease. And, high cutoffs signifies that above this threshold score patient is at high risk.

Comment: any details about how each model compute the cut off values? is it based on quantile?

Comment: yes, based on quantile and even target concentrations. Like depending upon cases for 1 and 0. And, also I am expecting scaled values to be in between 0 & 1. But, after using your mentioned formula I am getting negative values.

Comment: Sir, I have added R code with example. Please check for more clarity. I know its tough to explain without example. And, in some cases I cannot use 
quantiles. If you can suggest any other solution.

Comment: is your goal everything in scaled low  $<$ everything in scaled medium $<$ everything in scaled high?

Comment: or is your goal replace this line cutoff.high <- c(A=0.5, B=0.8, C=0.7) with a single number without scaling the raw number?

Comment: I want everything to scaled such that I can get a 1 (High,med,low) cutoff for whole data

Comment: if I always set $q_L=\frac13$ and $q_H=\frac23$, does it achieve your goal?

Comment: No, I dont think so because It may change to any ratio. Is there any other alternative without using quantiles.

Comment: We actually get high, medium, low based on 2 condition

Comment: 1.  when total positive predictive value for high records is above ~40-50%.

Comment: 2. When # of records for high + medium = low

Comment: we set cutoff such that it satisfies the above 2 conditions

Comment: proposed a new approach, but due to the first constraint, the numbers might get smaller.

Comment: Aah hard to understand. It would be helpful If you can give one example?

Comment: Sir, It would be helpful If you can explain your solution with small example?

Comment: added how to handle the upper limit for your data. the sum constraint is a barrier to cover the whole range from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: How you decide values for gamma, mu, lamba. Also, what do you mean by these Let DA,DB,DC denotes the data that was initially classified as "high". If I consider everything to be as high point then how I decide Li & Hi. sorry for formatting.

Comment: You have the freedom to choose as long as it satisfy those condition. For starter, let $\lambda = 0$ and $\mu_j = \mu$ a constant and solve for $\mu$. If you consider everything as high... how do u satisfy your second condition.

Comment: I am so confused. To be honest. I am not getting it. Can you please explain it with a good example. I would really appreciate. I am stuck on this part from so long

Comment: what are the data that are classified as high initially according to your model $A$, $B$, $C$?

Comment: So, these are my data points modelA.output <- c(0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2)
modelB.output <- c(0.7, 0.2, 0.8, 0.9, 0.3)
modelC.output <- c(0.8, 0.1, 0.5, 0.6)

Comment: And, cutoff.high <- c(A=0.5, B=0.8, C=0.7), cutoff.low <- c(A=0.3, B=0.7, C=0.4)

Comment: focus on model $A$, your High_cutoff > 0.5, what are the data that are considered as "high"?

Comment: It should be 0.9

Comment: hence $D_A = \{ 0.9 \}$, we obtain $D_B$ and $D_C$ similarly.

Comment: Oh ok. And, how do you check for constraints and set values for mu, sigma and gamma.

Comment: Also, are you just scaling the $D_A$, $D_B$, $D_C$ ?

Comment: To obtain something that work initially, set $\lambda = 0$, $\mu_j = \frac{1}{|D_A|+|D_B|+|D_C|} \frac9{20}$. Everything has to be scaled down due to your first constraint.

Comment: what if we have $D_A$={0.9,0.8,0.9,0.7}, $D_B$={0.8,0.7}, $D_C$={0.7,0.8,0.9} ? What we do with other data which fall under $L_i$

Comment: That is not possible according to my interpretation, when total positive predictive value for high records is above $\sim 40-50\%$. Did I misinterpreted your condition. My interpretation would be for the first model the moment you detect $0.9>0.4$ you would push the others to the other category. Did I misinterpreted that?

Comment: I can have multiple values in $D_A$ based on high cutoffs. As you can see from programming example. To keep this question simple I just want to rescale all values from model_A ,B , C based on $L_i$ and $H_i$ such that I can combine back all values and compare them based on single cutoff

Comment: I see. I misinterpreted your requirement which is why I feel that it's a strange requirement. For your info, the requirement that number of records for high + medium = low suggest that you might want to set $q_L = 0.5$.

Comment: I can send you what I have tried so far. You can suggest some changes and let me know whether it is correct.

Comment: A possible bug in your code is rather than $\frac{ x-\mu ){ \sigma } $ you are doing $x - \frac{\mu}{\sigma}$.  Your question is too open ended for me to judge whether something is correct.

Comment: Yes and I have done some modification. I can edit my code and let you know. I have mapped new range for data points after subsetting them into Low, Medium and High using initial cutoffs.